# Как изменить адрес веб сокета не меняя сессию?

Tags: javascript, websocket

У меня есть код

```
   let url = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/sock/chat";
   const con = new WebSocket(url);
```

Который создает подключение через веб сокет.
Как мне изменить адрес подключения , например на `"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/sock/chat2"`
не меняя сессию подключения пользователя? Что бы данные уходили по другому адресу или можно было выбирать адреса.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

никак.... новый адрес - новая сессия

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/347202)

Comment: для меня вопрос понятен, не требует дополнения и корректировки, и предложенный ответ - самый полный.